# Can I keep rolling file in log4j2 even though the log is empty

Tags: log4j2, rollingfileappender

I have a program in java to write log using log4j2 that configured in xml configuration file.
Can I keep rolling file in log4j2 even though the log is empty. I need to use the archived log generated by log4j2. Now the archived log is only created if the log is not empty, if there is no log then the archived is not created. But I want log4j2 to keep generated the log even there is empty log. Any advice?

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<Appenders>
    <RollingFile
        fileName="logs/app-%d{yyyyMMdd}.log"
        filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM-dd}/app-%d{yyyyMMdd}-%i.log.gz"
        name="app_file">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d %p %m %ex%n
            </Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
                size="100 MB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20" />
    </RollingFile>

    <Console name="stdout" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %highlight{%class{1.}:%L} [%c] [%p] %m%n" />
    </Console>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger additivity="false" includeLocation="true"
          name="app">
        <AppenderRef ref="app_file" level="trace"/>
        <AppenderRef  ref="stdout" level="trace"/>
    </Logger>

    <Logger level="error" name="com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot">
    </Logger>
    <Logger level="error" name="org.springframework">
    </Logger>

    <Root includeLocation="true">
        <AppenderRef ref="stdout" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

I also added some code below in my java code

`System.setProperty("Log4jContextSelector",
        "org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector");`

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the file only roll over when something is written into the file. I think that basically you should do some customization, here are 2 options:

1. Set a timer, log empty string periodic to trigger the roll over.
2. Override the `RollingFile` and roll over file whatever you want.